# Efficient AI handling when you have bools (avoiding cache misses)

Tags: ai

So I am trying to optimize my ai in my game i am working on in C++

This is an example of what ai will look like

```
    class EntityUnit : public CEntity
{
public:
    enum CUnitTypeEnum // Enumerator used for finding the type of entity
    {
        Infantry,
        Tank,
        Aircraft,
        Transport,
        Naval,
        BipedalTank,
        NA,
    };

    enum CUnitTypeState
    {
        Idle,
        AttackingUnit,
        Defend,
        SearchForStrategicPoint,
        GuardResource,

    };

    enum CUnitMoveType  // Controls how the units will move to an area
    {
        Normal,  // pathfinding will take into account influence map costs
        Aggressive, // pathfinding will not take into account influence map costs
        Evasive,  // Pathfinding will add extra cost to influence map where units have occupied
        NavalNormal,
        NavalAgressive,
        NavalEvasive,
        AircraftNormal,
        AircraftAggresive,
        AircraftEvasive,
        NUKE
    };
private:

    IModel* UnitModel;

    float unit_x;
    float unit_y;
    float unit_z;
    float height;
    float width;

    float maxhealth;
    float currenthealth;
    float strength;

    float speed;
    float util_timer_movedelay = 0; // TIMER - used for delaying movement per frame

    float buildtime;
    float cost;
    float unit_model_scale;

    string unitname;
    string unitdescription;


    CUnitTypeEnum CUnitType;

    vector<gen::CVector3*> pathfinding;
    Vector3 TargetWaypoint;
    Vector3 SourceWaypoint;


    // AI BOOLEAN & STATE
    bool underattack; // IS the unit under attack / do we wan't to perform combat()
    bool reachedwaypoint; // used to detect whether reached waypoint
    bool unitGarrisoned; // IS this unit inside a cities garrison ?
    bool unitInSquad; // is this unit in an ai control squad ? 


    CUnitTypeState State = Idle; // Starts off idle, == not doing anything

    string NukeSource;
    string NukeTarget;
    gen::CVector3 VNukeSource;
    gen::CVector3 VNukeTarget;
```

Its a polymorphic entity, that will call in my game loop the AI polymorphic function update() now I understand some general concepts, and I have been told or am under the impression, that the reason for my large slowdown in performance, is because the CPU' tries to guess what a enum or bool will be when you use a lot of them in a tightly closed loop, can anyone explain why this is ? and also how to avoid this or what is the most efficient way to avoid this when my AI needs to be able to change through certain behaviours and know things about its world that is true and false.

Comment: How can you be so sure you have issues with code path prediction? Did you profile your code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the entire thing was based on faulty assumptions on your part that the stated problem even _was_ a problem at all (as noted under Peter's answer, below).

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer, that does not seem like a legitimate close reason (and certainly not opinion based). If the problem can be defined as *faulty assumptions*, detail as such, in an answer.

Comment: This looks on-topic to me, though it might have benefited from more research into branch misprediction and profiling information to establish whether this is the root cause of a real problem in the user's game. I think the up/downvote system is enough to handle that, so I'm voting to leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

The top answer (ahead by a little over 20'000 votes, so unlikely to change) answers the why, while the question answers what you can do about it.

And to place the answer here: Branch prediction, and it can be improved by sorting. However, don't get your hopes up. I haven't seen your code, but this is unlikely to be the primary bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find this and I searched quite a while :( must need to check eyesight!

Comment: Oh and @Peter this is true, there is another bottleneck in my graphics handling classes, since I'm using my attempts to recreate free libraries, since I'm dealing with a large amount of entities, but I'm trying to streamline everything possible.